# Multiple buttons with same class and no unique id, How to identify which one is clicked with vanilla JS only

Tags: javascript

I made a react component of simple button with onclick ripple effect. Now the problem is that if I have more than 1 button, no matter which button I click othe animation appear on the first button. How do I identify which button is clicked and have the animation run on that button
I am only using vanilla JS, since I am new to programming.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./CommonButtons.css"
import "./DefaultButton.css"

class  DefaultButton extends Component {
state = {  }
AddRipple = (Class)=>
{

    let pro = document.getElementsByClassName("Button")
    pro[0].innerHTML = "<span class='Button-ripple'></span>" + 
    pro[0].innerHTML;

    let height = 
 (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("Button") 
[0]).width)
    document.getElementsByClassName("Button-ripple") 
[0].style.height=`${height}`;

    pro[0].addEventListener("animationend", function(){
        pro[0].innerHTML="<span class='ButtonText' style='color: 
 white;'>DEFAULT</span>"
    });

    console.log(Class)

  }

 render() { 

    let {color, BG, Text} = this.props;

    return ( 

        <button className="Default Button" onClick= 
 {()=>this.AddRipple(this)}>
            <span className="ButtonText" style={{color:`${color}`}}> 
 {`${Text}`.toUpperCase()}</span>
        </button>


     );
}
}

export default DefaultButton;
```

HOw can I identify and add the effect on correct Button

Comment: Any reason why you use non unique keys?

Comment: I want this component to be reusable without having to reach out its code and add unique id everytime.

Comment: Your title says vanilla JS but this is clearly ReactJS. What answer did you really want?

Comment: I am still looking for Vanilla JS answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the DefaultButton class create a field `buttonRef`

```
    class  DefaultButton extends Component {
        state = {  }
        buttonRef = React.createRef()
        ...
    }
```

Pass the field to button's ref prop, like this:

```
 <button ref={this.buttonRef} className="Default Button" ... />
```

When you invoke the `AddRipple` method, instead of `this`, pass the ref's property `current`:

```
() => this.AddRipple(this.buttonRef.current)
```

Change the method's implementation. Insteaf of `Class`, take as a paremeter `buttonElement`, which will be your button. Don't query the document for the button, as you don't need it anymore.

```
AddRipple = (buttonElement) => {
   ...
}
```

Refs mechanism is exactly what you need here, it's described here:
https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html